# I squared for measuring homogeneity

Tags: meta-analysis, biostatistics, heterogeneity

I can't seem to find a simple resource that explains what I can use the I2 (derived from Cochrane's Q), often used in meta-analyses for, exactly. Most, if not all resources I find on the subject go on some from of tangent, mostly ending in "it depends".

If I find a published meta-analysis, citing an I squared value to assess heterogeneity, with values low as 25% or less, can I, as a non-statistician (physician) say that this means the studies are homogeneous and whatever intervention they were using is probably working across different demographies (assuming that's what their results are)?

Comment: It is often used in medical meta-analyses.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68205/calculating-i-squared-in-meta-analysis-given-tau-squared?rq=1